# Angular - Active Class not being applied

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

Routes

```
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: 'profile/about', component: AboutComponent },

  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

CSS

```
.active {
    border-bottom: 4px solid dodgerblue !important;
}
```

NAV

```
<a routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Posts</a> //WORKS FINE
    <a href="/profile/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a> //ACTIVE CLASS NOT APPLIED
```

Why does it work fine for the first one (Posts) but it does not work when I go to the About Page?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I used href in the second one and not routerlink

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).